# Sort array in Java

Tags: java

What happened if I sort a Java array with criteria based on its element?

```
Point[] points = new Point[10];
Arrays.sort(temp, points[0].SLOPE_ORDER);
```

Will this be a recursive call?

SLOPE_ORDER is a comparator:

```
public final Comparator<Point> SLOPE_ORDER = new SlopeOrder();       // YOUR DEFINITION HERE

private class SlopeOrder implements Comparator<Point>
{
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what is  `points[0].SLOPE_ORDER` ?

Comment: Would it make a difference whether the sorting is recursive or not? Every recursion can be written as an iteration. Applying the blackbox principle that means: "Arrays.sort()" is working. IF this question is in the scope of homework like "Apply a recursive sorting algorithm" that answer is for sure not, what is expected.

Comment: SLOPE_ORDER should be a comparator function. It will be called each time the algorithm needs to compare two elements.

Comment: The big question is, why do you need to know if it will be a recursive call?

Answer (score 4):

See here:

[Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

So the answer is: no, it's not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the naming convention and the contract of `Array#sort`, `SLOPE_ORDER` is a `static final` member of the `Point` class that you are using. Specifically, it's a comparator that can be passed to the `sort` method.

To answer your question, nothing interesting will happen.

`Arrays.sort(temp, points[0].SLOPE_ORDER);`

will evaluate `points[0].SLOPE_ORDER` as the reference to the object and use its value as an argument to perform the sorting without needing to look at `points[0]` ever again (at least not in order to get `SLOPE_ORDER`.

If `SLOPE_ORDER` is both `static` and `final`, this can be replaced with

`Arrays.sort(temp, Point.SLOPE_ORDER);`

the result will be exactly the same and the code is much easier to understand.